# Magento 2.3.5 main.CRITICAL: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [news_to_date.sort_news_to_date]

Tags: magento2.3, error, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

This error is causing a lot of problems on our site with our products disappearing. I think this error happens at times when certain products are edited from admin. Errors are below.

I think this has to do with Elastic Search and sorting attributes or something with Layered Navigation. I am not sure. I know in catalogue_eav_attribute table news_to_date is attribute Id 94 in database. But I am not sure how to fix.

Any help would be much appreciated.

> main.CRITICAL:
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No
> mapping found for [news_to_date.sort_news_to_date] in order to sort
> on","index_uuid":"UC9WC9aUSue1pmOFxrjZ3g","index":"magento2live_webpos_productsearch_fulltext_1_v7"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
> shards
> failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2live_webpos_productsearch_fulltext_1_v7","node":"Ml8-bmNiSkqu5yLzk8on9g","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No
> mapping found for [news_to_date.sort_news_to_date] in order to sort
> on","index_uuid":"UC9WC9aUSue1pmOFxrjZ3g","index":"magento2live_webpos_productsearch_fulltext_1_v7"}}]},"status":400}
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400):
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No
> mapping found for [news_to_date.sort_news_to_date] in order to sort
> on","index_uuid":"UC9WC9aUSue1pmOFxrjZ3g","index":"magento2live_webpos_productsearch_fulltext_1_v7"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards
> failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"magento2live_webpos_productsearch_fulltext_1_v7","node":"Ml8-bmNiSkqu5yLzk8on9g","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No
> mapping found for [news_to_date.sort_news_to_date] in order to sort
> on","index_uuid":"UC9WC9aUSue1pmOFxrjZ3g","index":"magento2live_webpos_productsearch_fulltext_1_v7"}}]},"status":400}
> at
> /var/www/vhosts/upperlimitsinc.com/httpdocs/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:641)"}
> []

**UPDATE:**
We have discovered something else with this error. It seems to trigger and only happen when we change certain products to different categories. I have not been able to recreate this error on localhost only happens on Production. So it seems to only happen on Category Change of Products.

Comment: do you need the attribute 'news_to_date' to be a sorting criteria on your catalog pages?

Comment: Hi @DianaBotean, yes, we kind of do need set news_to_date as a sorting criteria. Today, i saw that switching new_to_date to searchable to YES may fix. It was set to NO. So I have tried setting is_searchable to YES. But did just try that today. So will see if that fixes it.

Comment: It happened again today after changing that setting, changing the setting I changed did not help. 

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"No mapping found for [news_to_date.sort_news_to_date] in order to sort on","index_uuid":"yjxQRO8hRjiFJx0ZRB8RKw","index":"magento2live_webpos_prod

Comment: I do know 'news_to_date' is attribute ID 94. Column used_to_sort_by in catalog_eav_attribute table on attribute ID 94(news_to_date) Column used_to_sort_by is set to 1/yes and that is what is probably causing problems and turning that off, could possibly fix. But we are wanting to keep that turned on.

Comment: i see. and what is the type of the attribute?

Comment: Hi @DianaBotean, Thank you for the help on this. Its backend_type is "datetime".

Comment: Hi @DianaBotean, We have discovered something else with this error. It seems to trigger and only happen when we change certain products to different categories. I have not been able to recreate this error on localhost only happens on Production. So it seems to only happen on Category Change of Products.

Comment: ok, but this is totally weird and should not cause such an issue... i hope you find the solution soon

Comment: After updating to Magento2.4.2pt-1. We do not receive this error anymore.